# RN Firebase DynamicLink resolveLink not working in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to get my dynamic link properties using the function [resolveLink()](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/dynamic-links#resolveLink).

I try:

```
dynamicLinks().resolveLink("https://myapp.page.link/teste").then(link => console.log(link))
```

In Android this works fine, but in ios i receive this error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: [dynamicLinks/not-found] Dynamic link not found
NativeFirebaseError: [dynamicLinks/not-found] Dynamic link not found
onPress@http://192.168.2.43:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:183968:49
_performTransitionSideEffects@http://192.168.2.43:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:62011:22
_receiveSignal@http://192.168.2.43:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:61953:45
onResponderRelease@http://192.168.2.43:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:61862:34
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl@http://192.168.2.43:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12842:21
invokeGuardedCallback@http://192.168.2.43:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12936:42
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@http://192.168.2.43:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12940:36
executeDispatch@http://192.168.2.43:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:13012:48
executeDispatchesInOrder@http://192.168.2.43:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:13032:26
executeDispatchesAndRelease@http://192.168.2.43:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14107:35
forEach@[native code]
```

The link was created in Firebase Console and opens the iOS app normaly.

Who can help me?